# Como percorrer um objeto em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Como percorrer o objeto abaixo com JavaScript?

```
var obj = {
  "column01": "Coluna 01",
  "column02": "Coluna 02",
  "column03": "Coluna 03",
  "column04": "Coluna 04",
  "column05": "Coluna 05",
  "column06": "Coluna 06",
  "column07": "Coluna 07",
  "column08": "Coluna 08",
  "column09": "Coluna 09",
  "column10": "Coluna 10"
};
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ou [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) para iterar as chaves e os valores do objeto:

```js
const obj = {
  "column01": "Coluna 01",
  "column02": "Coluna 02"
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item + " = " + obj[item]);
});

for (const property in obj) {
  console.log(property + " = " + obj[property]);
}
```

Ou com [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const obj = {
  "column01": "Coluna 01",
  "column02": "Coluna 02"
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(key + ' ' + value);
}
```

Comment: +1 pela síntaxe especial `[ ]` em combinação ao `for... of`.

Answer (score 10):

O correto é utilizar `for in` com checagem de propriedade para evitar possiveis erros. Exemplo:

```
var obj = {
    "column01": "Coluna 01",
    "column02": "Coluna 02",
    "column03": "Coluna 03"
};

for (var column in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
        console.log(column); // column01
        console.log(obj[column]); // Coluna 01
    }
}
```

Porque usar `obj.hasOwnProperty`?

Se por acaso algum Object ter alguma alteração no `Prototype` será passado no `for`. Exemplo:

```
Object.prototype.test = function() {};
Object.prototype.test2 = function() {};

var obj = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
};

for (var letter in obj) {
    console.log(letter);
}

// a
// b
// test
// test2
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o uso do Object.keys, por exemplo:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key); //column01...
    console.log(obj[key]); //Coluna 01...
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const obj = {
    "column01": "Coluna 01",
    "column02": "Coluna 02"
};

for (const column in obj) {
    console.log(column, '=', obj[column]);
}
```