# Como dar um Loop em um objeto javaScript

Tags: javascript, loop, objetos

Um objeto não tem o mesmo comportamento de um objeto durante um loop em JavaScript.

Esse exemplo:

```
let obj = {
  casa1: {
    cor: 'azul',
    quartos: 2,
  },
  casa2: {
    cor: 'vermelho',
    quartos: 4,
  },
}
```

Não funciona o forEach padrão:

```
obj.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item)
})
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como percorrer um objeto em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173293/como-percorrer-um-objeto-em-javascript)

Comment: Porque usar um array como se fosse um objeto?

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas enfim: quando vc tem chaves do tipo "alguma coisa 1", "alguma coisa 2", etc, é um sinal de que **talvez** você devesse usar um array em vez de um objeto: algo como `let casas = [ {cor: 'azul', quartos: 2}, {cor: 'vermelho', quartos: 4} ]` - se todos os elementos representam casas, ter as chaves que indicam "casa N" se torna meio redundante, pois o número de cada casa pode simplesmente ser a posição delas no array. E como agora vc tem um array, dá para fazer `casas.forEach(etc...)` ou mais simples: `for (let casa of casas) { console.log(casa.cor) etc }`

Answer (score 2):

Uma possível solução seria:

Converter o objeto em Array

```
let casas = Object.values(obj);
```

Percorrer o Array normalmente

```
casas.forEach((casa) => {
 console.log(casa.cor);
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Tenta isso:

```
var listCasas = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        console.log(obj[i].cor + ' ' + obj[i].quartos);
    }
}

listCasas();
```

Comment: se o código está numa function, não deveria passar o obj por parametro?

Comment: Aliás, para que criar uma função? E [anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/112052) ainda, qual o ganho em fazer isso? (nesse caso, nenhum) - De qualquer forma, com ou sem função, esse código não funciona, porque objetos não possuem o atritbuto `length` (funcionaria se fosse um array) - veja: https://ideone.com/5NF56s